# Double restart and Failed SCCM installer: 0x40010004(1073807364)

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-installer, sccm

We have a package which was recently deployed in SCCM. This package requires dot net 4.8 as a pre requisite and installs dot net 4.8 before installing the application. It is expected for the machine to restart after installing dot net 4.8 . But, in case of this package, even after restarting once post dot net 4.8 installation, it restarts the machine once again after starting the application install and this time without even a warning or 1.5 hours of countdown. Even after restarting the machine twice, the application is not successfully installed.

When clicked on more information on "Failed" status in SCCM, the error code is `0x40010004(1073807364)`. Please see below image for reference.

[image]

So, I wanted to know if this is an issue with SCCM or if this is an issue with the application msi files and .cmd script?